# Column with block times in r depending on the hour interval

Tags: r, row

> Hi! So I have this data set (see image) and I new to build a new column where,
>   depending on the hour of the class, will say if the class is given at
>   the 1º, 2º, ... block of the day. For example, the first block is from
>   8 am to 9 am, the second block is from 9am to 10 am,... It also
>   happens that most classes will ocupy more than just one block, most of
>   them occupies 2 blocks so the format of the new column must take that in consideration. I already started the code with something like this (only for block 1):

```
datanew1$College_Hour <- case_when(
  interval(datanew1$Tijd.van, datanew1$Tijd.tot.en.met) %within% interval(8, 9) ~ "1")
```

> Any idea how to solve this? Thank you!!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTFc7.png)

Comment: One method you could use is to create a table of the start and end time of each block. Then cross join (cartesian product) that with the list of classes. Finally, filter based on whether the start time is in the block, the end time is within the block, or they surround the block.

Comment: So I created a table like the one you said. After this, I'm not sure if I get what you mean:
`Start Hours`       `End Hours`         Block
   <dttm>              <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 1900-01-08 08:00:00 1900-01-09 09:00:00     1
 2 1900-01-09 09:00:00 1900-01-10 10:00:00     2
 3 1900-01-10 10:00:00 1900-01-11 11:00:00     3
 4 1900-01-11 11:00:00 1900-01-12 12:00:00     4
 5 1900-01-12 12:00:00 1900-01-13 13:00:00     5
 6 1900-01-13 13:00:00 1900-01-14 14:00:00     6
 7 1900-01-14 14:00:00 1900-01-15 15:00:00     7
(...)

Comment: This smells like a homework problem so I'm not going to walk you through it but here is something about [cross joins](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) which is basically making every combination (hint: `dplyr::crossing`). Then you need to figure out how to filter down the results. Note that this isn't the only, or even fastest, method.